# symfony2 - twig - difference filter trans

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I wanted to know what is the difference between the `{% trans%} lorem ipsum {%endtrans%}` and `{{'lorem ipsum' | trans}}`

and also in which case use the block `{% trans%}`.

i don't understand the difference.thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the symfony documentation

> Using the translation tags or filters have the same effect, but with
>   one subtle difference: automatic output escaping is only applied to
>   translations using a filter. In other words, if you need to be sure
>   that your translated message is not output escaped, you must apply the
>   raw filter after the translation filter

```
{# text translated between tags is never escaped #}
{% trans %}
    <h3>foo</h3>
{% endtrans %}

{# strings and variables translated via a filter are escaped by default #}
{{ '<h3>bar</h3>'|trans|raw }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates